# Why for loop is not working in ionic ionViewWillEnter method

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I am calling a method "allComments()" in ionViewWillEnter() method, but it is not not binding name and profile every time I am entering in view. Not able to find any valid reason. There's no error in the code

```
allComments() {
this.comments=[];
let arr=[];
this.com=[];
console.log(this.challengeId)
this.https.get('https://dareost.firebaseio.com/comments/'
+this.challengeId+'.json').map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(x=>{
 this.com=x

for(let key in this.com) {
   this.comments.push(this.com[key])
 }
this.length = this.comments.length;

for(let i=0;i<this.comments.length;i++){
 let a=this.comments[i]
 console.log(a)
for(let key in a){

arr.push(a[key])
this.arr.push(a[key])

}


}


 for(let i=0;i<this.arr.length;i++){
   for(let j=0;j<this.users.length;j++){
    console.log(this.arr[i].commentedBy)

    if(this.arr[i].commentedBy == this.users[j].uid){
      console.log(this.users[j].name1)
      this.arr[i].name=this.users[j].name1
       console.log(this.arr[i])
      this.arr[i].profile=this.users[j].profileUrl
      }
    }
    }
```

It is sometimes not printing this.arr[i].name on console and sometime it gets print.

Comment: What is the output for the loop logs?

Comment: the output is loops are running always

Comment: I mean, what are all those console.logs inside the loops logging to the console. Btw, in cases like this you should use .forEach() for better legibility.

Comment: Can you share more context? Also you do a lot of heavy weight scripting in a lifecycle hook that is supposed to be light weight as it gets called pretty often

Comment: Can u tell how to make it light weight and at what point it is getting heavy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ionViewWillEnter() gets for a less time and heavy loops and heavy processes cannot get process during this time. It totally depends on the device's RAM. A device having good processing speed will not load heavy data while the device with slow processing speed can process heavy data.